# Trying to connect both a router and a laptop via PoE

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have a PoE, which I’ve been connecting to my router for years. If I needed a wired connection for some reason, I would also run an Ethernet cable between my laptop and my router.

My signal began getting unstable, so I started connecting my laptop via Ethernet cable directly to the PoE, and that solved all my problems. The issue is that my Ubiquiti PoE only has one LAN port, so if I connect my laptop, I have to disconnect my router. *I* have Internet, in other words, but no one else does.

I have an Ethernet switch, which I’ve tried connecting everything to in every possible permutation I can think of, but neither router nor laptop wants to pick up a signal unless I connect them directly to the PoE.

Closest I’ve come was my ethernet assigning itself an IP, and trying to fix that just ended in frustration and tears. Is there a way to wire everything together—either with the equipment I have or with equipment I don’t yet have, idc, I am tired and sad—and ensure that I get my awesome stable wired connection without kicking everyone off the Wi-Fi?

Here’s a diagram of what I’m working with.

[image]

Comment: What exactly _is_ a "PoE" in this context? Power-over-Ethernet doesn't seem to fit…

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the device that you are connecting through is an ethernet power injector.  In your diagram it has two ports, one labeled PoE and one labeled LAN.  This device doesn't provide any sort of network function, but instead is intended to provide power to an ethernet device via it's ethernet cable.  Your actual network connection is coming from the other end of the cable that is plugged into the "LAN" port on this device.  There is a good chance that this PoE device is completely unnecessary for most of your devices.  As far as getting your connection fixed there are two possibilities and each depend on what is connected to the LAN port of the PoE device.

1. The LAN connection goes directly to the equipment provided by your internet service provider.  In this case I would recommend plugging this cable into the WAN port of your wireless router.  This would allow your wireless devices to access the internet as well as plug in a few wired devices.  I would consider this the most likely scenario with the data at hand.
2. The LAN connection leads to a router that you have installed.  In this case you will probably want to make sure that router provides wireless networking and make use of it.

In order to be of any more help you'll need to provide model numbers on the PoE device, router and switch.  Also, you need to find out where the other end of the LAN cable terminates.

Also, you mention that your "signal" was getting weak.  It sounds like the router has all but died on you.  You should probably get a new one and re-establish your connections as they were before.

Comment: and don't buy another belkin